# "Library not found" error in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have create one application in which I try to archive the application, it show me following error but when I run the application then it will work perfectly.

```
ld: library not found for -lz
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Name of the library?

Comment: Hey, sorry but i don't which library is missing for this error b'cs application run perfectly but only archive in not created.

Comment: `lz` is the `libz` library. I'm not sure why you are getting this error, I have used to link the `libz` with this way and submitted the archive successfully. I think you have to check the build settings of the app, there should be something wrong.